# How can I make axios return the correct type of buffer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, garmin

NOTE: when I first posted this question... I had no idea even where to begin or even how to give the question a good title.  After several comments, I added more data to the question and then eventually changed the question title to what it is now - thanks for the help everyone !

I am using Nodejs in a server application.  using Visual Code for my debugger.

I am reading a Garmin Fit File off disk using this code:

```js
    var fName = path.join(__dirname, './4861335825.fit');

    fs.readFile(fName, function (err, content) {
```

'Content' contains the following:

[image: file read buffer]

I am downloading the *SAME* Garmin Fit File via a REST call. Here is what the response looks like from the REST call

[image]

Here is the response header:

[image]

I am trying to get the response.data to be the same as when I read it off disk.  Here is the code where I try to create a buffer to read the data

```js
    encoding = 'utf8'
    const buf1 = Buffer.from(response.data, encoding);
```

Per Pointy's comment, I have tried using the following encoding for the REST call **BOTH** fail

```
encoding = 'utf8';
encoding = 'utf16le';
```

Here is what the buffer looks like:

[image: rest api buffer.from]

The files are the **SAME**, the difference is one read off disk and the other is trying to be read from the response.data from the REST call that downloads it.

The data appears to be the same in the two buffers:

```js
[14, 16, 77, ...]
```

However, the type and sizes are radically different:

[image: buffer compare]

I should also state, the file that is read from disk successfully parses using the fit-file-parser.  The one from the REST call fails to parse.

Here is the parsing code
I am using this parser: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fit-file-parser

```
    // Create a FitParser instance (options argument is optional)
    var fitParser = new FitParser({
        force: true,
        speedUnit: 'km/h',
        lengthUnit: 'km',
        temperatureUnit: 'kelvin',
        elapsedRecordField: true,
        mode: 'cascade',
        });

        var error = null;
        var data = null;
        try{
            fitParser.parse(responseData, function (error, data){

                if(error){
                    console.log(error);
                    return null;
                }

                return data;
            });
        }
        catch(err){
            console.log('error',err);
        }
```

How can I make the buffer from the REST download the same as the one that is read off disk?

Comment: Your Buffer you decided to use encoding, but for you readFile you never, maybe try using `utf8` for you readFile too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6870228/keith when I parse the file off disk it succeeds. when I parse the file from REST call it fails.

Comment: You're telling the client-side code to interpret the content as a UTF-8 encoded character stream. Is it?  *edit* — wait, is that HTTP request being made from Node? I guess so.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy - update question for types of encoding used.  ( this is all backend code )

Comment: What are the response headers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/446747/josh-trow - added response header pic

Comment: You can just type "@" plus the name of a user to refer to them, you don't need the complete user profile link

Comment: The byte sequence 14, 16, 77 doesn't look like a UTF-8 character sequence to me. If that gets *interpreted* as UTF-8 by anything, some byte sequences may coincidentally look like two or three-character Unicode code points. Thus the misinterpreted buffer won't necessarily be exactly twice the size of the raw byte buffer size.

Comment: @MLissCetrus `application/octet-stream` is kinda a generic catchall, often use for binary files - do you have the endpoint documentation for where that call is being made to? I suspect it's not returning the format of file you expect.

Comment: @josh.trow - thanks that's a good suggestion... I will follow up with Garmin

Comment: @MLissCetrus It looks, based on size, that you actually are getting just the byte array back but axios is treating it as a String. 5481 is close enough to 5429 to me to say that's the same file - the problem seems to be how axios is interpreting it. Can you force it to give you a byte array instead it converting it to a string first?

Comment: @josh.trow - I have no idea how to do that... hence why I posted here :-)

Comment: @MLissCetrus You can tell it to give you a specifiec repsonseType (arrayBuffer here) and then make a Buffer from a binary object:  https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/513#issuecomment-347919776

Comment: josh.trow - your suggestion lead me down the path to the answer I posted - thanks

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @josh.trow for giving me a suggestion.

Here is what fixed this:

before:

```js
    var config = {
      headers:{Authorization:header}
    }
```

after:

```js
    var config = {
      responseType: 'arraybuffer',
      headers:{Authorization:header}
    }
```

And the axios call returns the same buffer as the file read does !

[image]